# Modifying a Facebook event search: Can you search for events by specific date?

Tags: facebook, search

So Im looking to modify the following search. I'd like to limit the results to a specific date.

In this case, I searched Facebook for: "Events my friends are invited to that are in November 2015"

The resulting URL was:

https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/events-invited/2015/nov/date-2/events/intersect

The results are ALL events that my friends have been invited to in November.

Im wondering if there is a way to limit the results by a specific date...say November 15th?

Ive tried several variations but nothing I've tried so far will limit the results down to a specific date (nov 15th)

If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated!

Comment: November 15th happens to be a Sunday. The closest I have been able to get is "Events named "Sunday" in Washington, District of Columbia in November 2015" -- but that requires the word "Sunday" to be in the event title...

Answer (score 0):

That´s not the Graph API, it´s the Graph Search. You can´t use that one outside of Facebook, because that would be scraping and scraping is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You can only search for events by name, using the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

...assuming your question is not about Facebook in general, but about programming. Because Stackoverflow is a platform for programming only.

Comment: You are correct. I didnt mention "Graph API." I was indeed speaking about the Graph Search.

And perhaps, to your reply,  this isnt the place for the question.

I wasnt looking to scrape the page. I was actually looking to modify the Graph search to find more specific results for personal use and NOT to scrape the page.

You are correct though...the question might fall outside of the forum. I'll try elsewere...unless someone knows the answer off the top of their head...?